# Visual Studio 2017 cannot see any of the tables etc in my SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio finds my server and my database, but will not find any of the tables, views, stored procedures, etc. I am using VS 2017 and SSMS 17.

Any ideas of what it could be? I've tried everything.

Comment: What do you mean Visual Studio can't find? Did you write a program to access the data? Or are you using Database Explorer? Be specific.

Comment: are you able to use Management studio to connect to your database and look at everything? Do you have enough permissions.. if you can connect to your DB but not see any thing.. it is more than likely a permission issue..

Comment: I'm using SQL server Object Explorer to connect to the database,  I go into the node for the database then to the tables and no tables are in the folder.

Comment: I am able to use management studio with no problems.  I'm the owner of the database and I use the sa account to access it in SSMS.  What should the permissions be set to?